# PHP Nested Navigation

Tags: php, recursion, navigation

I am building out a database-driven navigation, and I need some help in a method to build my data structure. I'm not very experienced with recursion, but that is most likely the path this will take. The database table has an id column, a parent_id column, and a label column. The result of calling the method provides me with the data structure. The way my data structure should result in the following:

- Records with a parent_id of 0 are assumed to be root elements.
- Each root element contains an array of children if a child exists which holds an array of elements containing the parent_id equal to the root element id.
- Children may contain a children array containing parent_ids equal to the immediate child (this would be the recursive point)
- When a record exists that contains a parent_id which isn't 0, it gets added to the array of the children elements.

Here is how the data structure should look:

```
$data = array(
  'home' => array(    
      'id' => 1,
      'parent_id' => 0,
      'label' => 'Test',
      'children' => array(
          'immediatechild' => array(
              'id' => 2,
              'parent_id' => 1,
              'label' => 'Test1',
              'children' => array(
                 'grandchild' => array(
                     'id' => 3,
                     'parent_id' => 2,
                     'label' => 'Test12',
             ))
         ))
  )
```

);

Here's something I came up with in a few moments. Its not correct, but its what I want to use and Id like some help fixing it.

```
<?php
// should i pass records and parent_id? anything else?
function buildNav($data,$parent_id=0)
{
   $finalData = array();
   // if is array than loop
   if(is_array($data)){
      foreach($data as $record){
          // not sure how/what to check here
        if(isset($record['parent_id']) && ($record['parent_id'] !== $parent_id){
            // what should i pass into the recursive call?            
            $finalData['children'][$record['label'][] = buildNav($record,$record['parent_id']);
         }
      }
    } else {
       $finalData[] = array(
        'id' => $data['id'],
        'parent_id' => $parent_id,
        'label' => $data['label'],         
     )
   } 
    return $finalData
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you are using MySQL as the datastore then you might like this: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ for the DB side of things

Comment: FIxed. Im looking for php code to build out the navigation data structure

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're here to help out, but not to just write code on request.

Comment: I wish I could say I've gotten anywhere, but I haven't. I don't really know how to solve this (I get confused with recursion). Furthermore, I don't really know how to program recursion using PHP.

Comment: "I don't know how to program recursion using PHP" Well, as in most other languages by calling a function from within itself.

Comment: Lol. That was pretty dumb of me to say. I just came up with something in a few moments. It's not right, but its a good start

Comment: if(is_array($records){ should be if(is_array($records)){ ...

Comment: Thanks. Im at work and did this in notepad with no php access. In any case, this is my first recursive problem Ive ever tried coding. Is my answer close to the correct answer? Is there anything to fix?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution (assuming you've got the data stored in relational represenation using the parent id as a FK to indicate the hierarchy) is to just brute force it:

```
 $start=array(
     array('parent_id'=>0, 'title'=>'Some root level node', 'id'=>100), 
     array('parent_id'=>0, 'title'=>'Other root level node', 'id'=>193),
     array('parent_id'=>100, 'title'=>'a child node', 'id'=>83),
     ....
 );
 // NB this method will work better if you sort the list by parent id

 $tree=get_children($start, 0);

 function get_children(&$arr, $parent)
 {
    static $out_index;
    $i=0;
    $out=array();
    foreach($arr as $k=>$node) {
       if ($node['parent_id']==$parent) {
         ++$i;
         $out[$out_index+$i]=$node;
         if (count($arr)>1) {
             $out[$out_index+$i]['children']=get_children($arr, $node['id']);
         }
         unset($arr[$k]);
    }
    $out_index+=$i;
    if ($i) {
      return $out;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
 }
```

But a better solution is to use an [adjacency list model](http://www.sqlsummit.com/AdjacencyList.htm) for the data in the database. As an interim solution you might want to serialize the tree array and cache it in a file rather than parse it every time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Id prefer to use my method. Can you take a look at it and let me know if its doable? It probably needs to be fixed up.