# Tree issue in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, tree

i have a table General whose structure like this

```
----------------------------------
id    |    name       | parent_id
------------------------------------
1     | root_category | Null
2     | Appare        | 1
3     | Accessories   | 1
4     | Shirt         | 2
5     | Pants         | 2
6     | hand Bags     | 3
7     | jewelry       | 3
```

And i store the value of general table using from in my product table

product table which contain all the information about product

in product table

---

```
p_id       | 1 
p_name     | bla
p_weight   | 250
g_id       | 5      
g_name     | pants
g_parent   | 2
```

i Want to generate complete tree using

->g_id    -> g_name    -> g_parent

tree should look like this

```
Root Category
 - Apparel 
   -- Shirts
   -- Pants 
 - Accessories
   -- Handbags 
   -- Jewelry
```

i have tried recursive function but its not working which is

```
function get_categories($parent = $g_parent)
{
    $html = '<ul>';
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `general` WHERE `parent_id` = '$parent'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $current_id = $row['id'];
        $html .= '<li>' . $row['name'];
        $has_sub = NULL;
        $has_sub = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`parent_id`) FROM `general` WHERE    `parent_id` = '$current_id'"));
        if($has_sub)
        {
        $html .= get_categories($current_id);
        }
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}

print get_categories();
```

but its not working.... :(

Comment: And it doesn't occur to you to write down what _is_ happening?

Comment: nothing i think function is wromg

Comment: @M.I.T. that's not really helping. First you say it collapses something, but that would imply you're getting some output, and now you say nothing is being outputted? Try some basic debugging (with `var_dump` for instance) and check how the function runs, where it gets, what the contents of which variable are, etc.

Comment: For this type of query, you'd be better of with [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Nested Navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450041/php-nested-navigation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this... its working code.. also see the output screenshot (*output screen*)

```
<?php

function get_categories(){

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con){
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("stackoverflow", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT g.`name` AS `category`, GROUP_CONCAT(gj.`name`) AS `name`
    FROM `general` g INNER JOIN `general` gj ON g.`id` = gj.`parent_id` GROUP BY g.`id` ");


    $i=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $data[$i]['category'] = $row['category'];
        $data[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
        $i++;
    }

    $html = $data[0]['category']."<br>";
    unset($data[0]);

    foreach($data as $key => $listing){

        $html           .= " - ".$listing['category']."<br>";
        $exp             = explode(",",$listing['name']);
        $count_exp   = count($exp);

        for($j=0; $j<=$count_exp-1;$j++){
            $html      .= "  -- ".$exp[$j]."<br>";
        }
    }

    return $html;
}

print_r(get_categories()); 
?>
```

> Output Screen

[image]

Comment: Hey @M.I.T any confusion regarding this please reply me and one more thing it is working code .....

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
print get_categories();
```

To

```
print get_categories(1);
```

an empty string is not going to match a NULL value in MySQL, hence you need to supply your starting id. Unless you wanna modify your function to do the extra checking if $parent is null.

Answer (score 0):

try this with some changing :

```
function get_categories($parent)
{
    $html = '<ul>';
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `general` WHERE `parent_id` = '$parent'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $current_id = $row['id'];
        $html .= '<li>' . $row['name'];
        $has_sub = NULL;
        $has_sub = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`parent_id`) as count FROM `general` WHERE    `parent_id` = '$current_id'")); // change here
        if($has_sub['count'] > 0) // change here
        {
        $html .= get_categories($current_id);
        }
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}

print get_categories(1); // change here
```